# Three-Second Delay for Closing Unreachable IP in Windows OS

Tags: python, windows, sockets

***PLEASE TEST WITH AN UNREACHABLE IP THAT IS IN YOUR DOMAIN AND WITH WINDOWS OS***

---

```
import socket
import datetime

IPADDR = '192.168.1.141'
PORTNUM = 5600
PACKETDATA = "f1a525da11f6".encode()

while(True):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
    #s.connect((IPADDR, PORTNUM))        
    #s.send(PACKETDATA)
    s.sendto(PACKETDATA, (IPADDR, PORTNUM))
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    s.close()
```

---

> Windows Socket Close Time for Unreachable IP(with UDP): 3 seconds
>    Ubuntu Socket Close Time for  Unreachable  IP(with UDP):   0 Second

Just copy and run that codes at above and see results.
***Why I am getting that three-second delay? How to reduce that three-second to the zero?***

Comment: But, how can the system know that the IP is unreachable? If it is in a different network and there is no gateway, then yes, you can. But if it is in the same network, the OS has to try and see if anybody replies to that IP, and that will take a while.

Comment: Use the [`socket.settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) method.

Comment: Time is required to determine if a potentially reachable address is not infact reachable, the operating system does not/cannot maintain a list of live addresses/endpoints - requests are issued then timeout in the absence of a response.

Comment: Given that you're using UDP there (for which there is no indication of whether a packet successfully arrived), the only plausible reason for the delay is ARP resolution by the underlying OS as it tries to solicit the MAC address for the IP. I doubt this behavior can be changed by application code.

Comment: If that's UDP, what does `s.connect()` even *mean*?

Comment: @Phylogenesis . It's not important, I 've updated codes and I got the same three-second delay.

Comment: @rodrigo. Please try with Ubuntu. In that case, there is no delay.

Comment: Probably because on that machine there is no route to the destination so it can immediately fail.  What you are looking for is not possible in a general sense.

Comment: @JasonMusgrove. Thank you so much. I think same with you.